LOOKER DATA STUDIO - Relative Indexing / Percentage to Normalize data
I have a table from GBQ connected to looker data studio where I want to normalize and present the data eg radar chart. It contains some of the columns Cluster, Nod. My calculation (averaging) will be done on the NOD column



Cluster
Nod




0
3


0
4


1
2


2
1


1
9


3
8


4
6


4
8



The normalization (Relative index) will use this simple logic
cluster average (ie thesame cluster) / overall cluster average * 100

Breakdown of logic

taking an average of all cluster types (ie average of cluster type 0, thesame applies for cluster type 1,2,3,4.An average of the different cluster ie for clus1 is calculated, same for the other clusters. ie avg_clus1(6,7,7,8) --- avg_clus(9,3,4,6) --- avg_clus0(3,4)

An average of all the calculated averages above is then performed to obtain overall average. ie avg(clus0:clus4).
Finally a relative indexing is then performed to normalize the data
eg for clus1 = clus1 average / overall average * 100. Same applies to other clusters clus2 = clus2 average / overall average * 100.
Would be very grateful for any advice on implementing this in looker data studio. I cant seem to find a function on there to perform this.
